# Rsync exclude correct syntax

Tags: rsync

I want to copy a directory from remote machine to local using rsync, but without some inner folders.

I'm using this command:

```
rsync -rave --exclude 'js' --exclude 'css' --exclude 'fonts' root@{IP}:/rem_dir1/rem_dir2/public /local_dir1/local_dir2/public
```

But result of it is:

```
Unexpected remote arg: root@{IP}:/rem_dir1/rem_dir2/public
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1361) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I'm sure remote root is correct. So the problem is in rsync command syntax.

What is the correct way to exclude several folders using rsync?

For example we have `/public` folder which contains `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3`, `dir4` and `dir5`. How to copy **only** `dir1` and `dir2` from `/public`?

Answer (score 1):

As with your other question, the `-rave` makes no sense. You want just `-av`.

You can get fancy with include and exclude commands, but the easiest way to copy just two directories is just to list them:

```
rsync -av \
    root@{IP}:/rem_dir1/rem_dir2/public/dir1 \
    root@{IP}:/rem_dir1/rem_dir2/public/dir2 \
    /local_dir1/local_dir2/public/
```

where `\` is just line-continuation (so I can wrap the long line), and I deliberately only added `/` to the end of the destination path, not the source paths.